# dart backy - can not run basic example

Tags: dart, neural-network

I try to run example of Backy

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/backy

```dart
 import "package:backy/backy.dart";

 // 1.
 var neuron  = new TanHNeuron(); // returnes floatingpoint values between -1 and 1
 var student = new Backy([2, 2, 1], neuron);
 var trainer = new Trainer(backy: student, maximumReapeatingCycle: 200, precision: .1);

 // 2. Add the pattern whcih the network should learn
 trainer.addTrainingCase([-1,-1], [-1]);
 trainer.addTrainingCase([-1, 1], [-1]);
 trainer.addTrainingCase([ 1,-1], [-1]);
 trainer.addTrainingCase([ 1, 1], [ 1]);

 // 3. train all the traininCases up to 300 times and be satisfied with a precision of           .1
 print(trainer.trainOnlineSets()); // prints number loops it took to learn all      trainingcases

 // 4. After that you can use the neural network
 print(student.use([-1,-1]));
 print(student.use([-1, 1]));
 print(student.use([ 1,-1]));
 print(student.use([ 1, 1]));
```

Lines `trainer.addTrainingCase([-1,-1], [-1]);` give me error:

```dart
 Multiple markers at this line
 - Expected a method, getter, setter or operator declaration
 - Unexpected token '('
 - Undefined class 'trainer.addTrainingCase'
```

I really don't know why this error appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't run code outside a function or method. I don't know why the example is published this way but when you enclose it in a `main()` method you get rid of the errors and can run the example

```dart
import "package:backy/backy.dart";

 // 1.
 var neuron  = new TanHNeuron(); // returnes floatingpoint values between -1 and 1
 var student = new Backy([2, 2, 1], neuron);
 var trainer = new Trainer(backy: student, maximumReapeatingCycle: 200, precision: .1);

void main() {
 // 2. Add the pattern whcih the network should learn
 trainer.addTrainingCase([-1, -1], [-1]);
 trainer.addTrainingCase([-1, 1], [-1]);
 trainer.addTrainingCase([ 1, -1], [-1]);
 trainer.addTrainingCase([ 1, 1], [ 1]);

 // 3. train all the traininCases up to 300 times and be satisfied with a precision of           .1
 print(trainer.trainOnlineSets()); // prints number loops it took to learn all      trainingcases

 // 4. After that you can use the neural network
 print(student.use([-1, -1]));
 print(student.use([-1, 1]));
 print(student.use([ 1, -1]));
 print(student.use([ 1, 1]));
}
```